# What's the structure of this Hemingway sentence?

Tags: grammar, reading

I'm reading *The Old Man And The Sea* by Ernest Hemingway, and I'm confused by this sentence:

> Then, while the old man was clearing the lines and preparing the
> harpoon, the male fish jumped high into the air beside the boat to see
> where the female was and then went down deep, his lavender wings,
> *that* were his pectoral fins, *spread* wide and all his wide
> lavender stripes showing.

I wonder which part of sentence ***spread*** is? Is it a predicate or a non-finite?

Comment: Spread is a past participle not a present tense. "To spread" has past tense and past participle "spread".

Comment: “This Hemingway Sentence” or  “Hemingway’s Sentence”, but not “This Hemingway’s Sentence”. I’ve corrected it, but just so you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the structure of this sentence by Hemingway?

**Then**, (adv.)

**while the old man was clearing the lines and preparing the harpoon**, (adv.)

**the male fish** (NP)

**jumped** (V)

**high** (adv.)

**into the air** (adv.)

**beside the boat** (adv.)

**[in order] to see where the female was** (adv.)

**and** (conjunction)

**then** (adv.)

**went** (V)

**down** (adv.)

**deep**, (adj.)

**his lavender wings**, (NP)

{**that** (conjunctive pronoun – relative: ref = his lavender wings ) **were** (V) **his pectoral fins** (NP)} (non-defining relative clause),

**[were] spread wide and** - (spread = pp of verb)

**all his wide lavender stripes** (NP)

**[were] showing.** (V)

Comment: I was going to DV for answering a non-targetted question, but thought the work involved didn't warrant that. But you've decided to read an absolute construction (, his lavender wings ... spread wide ... ) as a second independent clause (; his lavender wings ... were spread wide ...).